# $(x+2y-4)dx - (2x-4y)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(\bar x + 2 \bar y) d \bar x - (2 \bar x - \bar y) d \bar y = 0 $

$\bar y = V \bar x $

$ d \bar y = V d\bar x + dV \bar x $

Plugged it in exactly like this and could not figure out how to separate it

$ ( \bar x + 2V \bar x )d \bar x - (2 \bar x - V \bar x) (V + dV \bar x) $

$ \bar x (1 + 2V) d \bar x - 2 \bar x (1 - V) (V + dV \bar x) = 0$

Comment: why the bar over $x$ and $y$ ? Notation are also not clear... $dV\bar x$ means $d\bar (V\bar x)$ or $\bar x dV$ ?

Comment: See here: https://mathhelpboards.com/differential-equations-17/solving-rational-odes-form-ax-c-dx-ex-fy-g-dy-0-a-26350.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  (x + 2y - 4)dx - (2x -4y)dy = 0 $$

Let $X = x + a$ and $Y= y+ b$ and let's see if we can choose suitable values for $a$ and $b$.

$$ (X - a + 2Y - 2b - 4)dX - (2X-2a - 4Y +4b)dY =0$$

It's easy to find what the "suitable" values should be, since we just want them to cancel out the constants! So we solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
-4 &= a + 2b\\
0 &= 2a - 4b
\end{align*}$$
I'll let you verify that the correct values are $a=-2$ and $b=-1$. This leaves us with
$$(X + 2Y)dX - (2X-4Y)dY=0$$

Now let $Y=VX$, and hence $dY=VdX+XdV$. Then

\begin{align}
X(1 + 2V)dX - X(2-4V)(VdX+XdV) &=0\\
X(1+4V^2)dX - X^2(2-4V)dV &=0\\
X(1+4V^2)dX &= X^2(2-4V)dV\\
\dfrac{1}{X}dX &= \dfrac{2-4V}{1+4V^2}dV
\\
\log \left|X \right|+C_1&=\tan^{-1}(2V)-\frac{1}{2}\log(4V^2+1)\\
2\log\left|X\right|+C_2&=2\tan^{-1}(2V)-\log(4V^2+1)\\
C_2&=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2Y}{X}\right)-\log\left(\frac{4Y^2}{X^2}+1\right)\\&\quad-2\log\left|X\right|\\
C_2&=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2Y}{X}\right)-\log\left(4Y^2+X^2\right)\\
C_2&=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y-2}{x-2}\right)\\&\quad-\log\Big(4(y-1)^2+(x-2)^2\Big)
\end{align}
which may also be written as

$$C_3=\log\Big(4(y-1)^2+(x-2)^2\Big)-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2y-2}{x-2}\right)$$

Comment: Ive seen this cancelling the constants and such but seperating i cant get the x in the  V equation to the X side

Comment: Can you continue?

Comment: I don’t see how you got to X(1+4V^2)dX - X^2(2-V)dV=0

Comment: \begin{align}&X(1 + 2V)dX - X(2-4V)(VdX+XdV)\\&=
X(1 + 2V)dX-X(2VdX+2XdV-4V^2dX-4XVdV)\\&=
X(1 + 2V-2V+4V^2)dX-X(2XdV-4XVdV)\\&=
X(1+4V^2)dX - X^2(2-4V)dV
\end{align}

Comment: @Omar: Were you able to finish this problem?

Comment: I think you should post full solution, I think you definitely helped but it’s been a long time, post full solution and I will accept it.

Comment: @Omar: Updated solution with integration steps.

Comment: Solution accepted